Type of sentence structure?
a: Such originality, clever, well crafted songs, George Harrison was the best Beatle.
b: Such original, clever, well crafted songs, George Harrison was the best Beatle.
c: Such originality...clever, well, crafted songs, George Harrison was the best Beatle.
Why doesn't a) work like b) in terms of original/originality, and is it fixed if I place the ellipsis after originality.

I don't much care for that ellipsis. George Harrison, the best Beatle, composed clever, well, crafted songs with such originality. b) has parallel adjectives. a) mixed a noun and adjectives in the same phrase.

I would use a dash or colon after "Such originality".

Such original, clever, well-crafted songs is a comment about the quality of the songs.
Such originality is a comment about the writer.
I would recommend you to add an exclamation mark and then start a new sentence. If you don't want to do that, you need something more than a comma after songs - a dash or a semicolon.

All three versions of Such ... songs can't start their sentences this way.  #b could work with some additional words but #a can't:
b1. As demonstrated in such original, clever, well-crafted songs ...
#c has an additional problem on top of what we see in #a, because of the comma after well.   The preferred way to describe the songs is well-crafted songs; well crafted songs works too, but well, crafted songs won't work.
well-crafted

My version would be:
George Harrison, the best Beatle, composed clever, well-crafted songs with such originality.
b) has parallel adjectives that work. a) has mixed a noun and adjectives in the same phrase which is awkward and non-parallel.
a: Such originality, clever, well-crafted songs, George Harrison was the best Beatle. This one doesn't work.
b: Such original, clever, well-crafted songs, George Harrison was the best Beatle.
However, I might add with there:
With such original, clever, well-crafted songs, George Harrison was the best Beatle.
Now, for c, the one below is a possibility:
c: Such originality! Clever, well-crafted songs, George Harrison was the best Beatle.
OR
Clever, well-crafted songs, George Harrison was the best Beatle—with such originality!
The em dash should be longer than the hyphen but my computer won't do that.

Please ignore the dv's. No other answer has as many options.

@MariosAthanasiou Thanks but just so  you know, we really shouldn't do: I'll scratch your back, if you scratch mine. :)
